# Can one instance of a class (not the class itself) be the parent of many instances of another class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vulkan

**Root Problem**

I am trying to build a render engine with Vulkan in C++. I am trying to remove the asset meshes, textures, and similar from within the engine structure where I had it for testing purposes to its own separate class. I need to access some of the objects stored in the render engine class because each asset need to be able to add themselves to the vector of vertices, and have access to the same `VkDevice` for example.

**First attempt**

The first method I tried was making the asset's constructor take the render engine as one of its arguments, then taking pointers to all the objects that I would need from the render engine for the asset. I still think that this method might work, but I could not declare the class for the render engine before the class for the asset because the render engine needs a vector of all the assets that it was managing in this scenario. Neither could I declare the class for the asset before the class for the render engine because then I could not take the render engine as an argument for the asset's constructor. This feels like it should have a trivial solution, but I could not find one, so I went off to try my second method.

**Second attempt**

The second method I tried was inheritance. However, I realized as I was experimenting with it that I did not know of a way to get one instance of the render engine class to be the parent of many instances of the asset class. Each asset wanted its own render engine, but I needed for each asset to inherit from the same render engine so that the render engine's objects would be the same for all assets and to avoid having many instances of the render engine to manage.

**Final thoughts**

I think that there is probably a simple way to do the first option, but I think that in the long run the second option will be more rewarding as it will be easier to manage, cleaner, lead to better organized code, and even teach me more about this great language that I am beginning to explore. I would prefer a solution that involves the second method, but I also don't really know if this is possible because it seems like inheritance does not work on a per instance basis. Finally, I am very much open to new ideas that do not involve either of these options.

**Final question**

Is there a method of going about inheritance that allows for many instances of one object to inherit from one instance of another object in C++?

Comment: You can't inherit instances, only classes. Also, the assets inheriting the "render" class (or object if that was possible) doesn't make sense. Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. An "asset" is not itself a "renderer". An asset can be *renderable* but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a method of going about inheritance that allows for many instances of one object to inherit from one instance of another object in C++?

No, you are mixing apples and oranges here.

Inheritance is a way to build one class off of one or more base classes. It has nothing to do with instances of those classes, and in C++ classes are not objects. So by deriving a class `D` from another class `B` you define `D` but you do not create any instances of either `B` or `D`.

When you create objects (instances) of `D`, these objects will all have the same binary layout that will include data members from `B` and `D`. That is, every object of class `D` will contain a base subobject of class `B`. You cannot create an object of class `D` without its base subobject of class `B` or with a different binary layout, e.g. by referencing `B` at a different address.

You could share data between different objects by using references or (smart) pointers, like `std::shared_ptr`. But this has nothing to do with class inheritance. You will have to use references and (smart) pointers as data members of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

> Can one instance of a class (not the class itself) be the parent of many instances of another class?

Technically yes... if those many instances are all sub objects within one complete object. Example (which is probably something that no one would ever write):

```
struct Base {};
struct Second : virtual Base {};
struct Third1 : Second {};
struct Third2 : Second {};
struct Derived : Third1, Third2 {};
```

Here, there is one instance of `Base` within `Derived`, and that `Base` instance is the (virtual) base of two separate instances of `Second`, both of which are indirect bases of `Derived`.

Even though the answer was "yes", I don't know if this would be of use in any use case.